# Searching for value and returning another in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have an excel sheet that has values in two cell (A1 & A2).
Cell B1 has either values of them and I want C1 to return the other value in column A.

I tried `HLOOKUP` but it only works if B1 has the value in A1. I need it to work both ways.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1=A1,A2,A1)
```

This should choose the opposite.

**EDIT#1:**

Test for blank first:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(B1=A1,A2,A1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have another question, the value in B1 is determined by a another input. Is there a way that C1 does not return the value until B1 has its value. With your formula, there is an output even if B1 still has no value

Comment: @user13472501  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Edit is working perfectly. Sometimes solutions lie in the simplest forms.Thank you so much for your time.